# MVC 3: Can't Load Partial View without Inheriting CSS from Master Page (Telerik Report Viewer + Bootstrap)

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-3, twitter-bootstrap, telerik-reporting

I'm having a css conflict/collision issue using Telerik Reporting in a MVC 3 application.  It's a known issue that there is a css issue with the standard Site.css and their report viewer.  However, our application is using Twitter Bootstrap for the UI css, and I cannot find the conflicting areas for anything.  Since I can't find the conflicting css (I'm not even sure if I would be able to fix it without breaking the rest of the css in the application), my second thought was to load the partial view without the css, which should, in theory, work with no problems.  However, I cannot get the partial view to load without inheriting the CSS from the master page.  The site is using the Razor view engine, and the partial view with the report viewer is using the web forms view engine since Telerik has not updated their reporting yet (this is with Q1 2013).  Is there any way I can force this view to load without inheriting any of the css from the Master Page (Layout.cshtml)?  My code is below:

Main Page

```
@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Reports";
}

<h2>Reporting</h2>

@Html.Partial("_UnderContructionPartial")

@{
  Html.RenderPartial("ReportViewer");
}
```

View with Report Viewer

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="Telerik.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=7.0.13.220, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a9d7983dfcc261be" Namespace="Telerik.ReportViewer.WebForms" TagPrefix="telerik" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="Telerik.Reporting, Version=7.0.13.220, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a9d7983dfcc261be" Namespace="Telerik.Reporting" TagPrefix="telerik" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head runat="server">
    <title>Report</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script runat="server">
      public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
      {
        // to avoid the server form (<form runat="server"> requirement
      }
      protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
      {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        var instanceReportSource = new Telerik.Reporting.InstanceReportSource();
        //instanceReportSource.Parameters.Add(new Telerik.Reporting.Parameter("UserName", ViewData["UserName"].ToString()));
        instanceReportSource.ReportDocument = new program1.Web.Reports.TestReport();
        ReportViewer.ReportSource = instanceReportSource;
        ReportViewer.ViewMode = ViewMode.PrintPreview;
      }
    </script>

    <form id="main" method="post" action="">
      <telerik:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer" Width="100%" Height="800px" runat="server">
      </telerik:ReportViewer>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult ReportViewer()
{
  return PartialView("ReportViewer");
}
```

This is what the report viewer looks like:

[image]

And this is what it "should" look like:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just ran into the same issue and after a little bit of head banging this is what I came up with.  Currently using MVC4 with Bootstrap.

I created a new .css file into ~/Content/ and added:

```
.InputButtonClass
{
    display: block;
    margin-top: 3px !important;
}

select
{
    height: 23px !important;
    font-size: 8pt !important;
}

input[type="text"], input[type="number"] .uneditable-input
{
    color: #555555;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 23px;
    line-height: 23px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding: 4px 6px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

input, textarea, .uneditable-input
{
    width: auto;
}

.ReportToolbar INPUT
{
    height: 11px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
}

#ReportViewer1_ReportToolbar_NavGr_CurrentPage_CurrentPage
{
    margin-top: 4px !important;
    padding: 3px 2px 3px 2px !important;
}
```

[image]

This made everything line up nearly perfect except the "Export" link, but I just increased the font size to 10pt and it looked fine.  The select arrow is a little crushed, but I can live with it for now.  Also I kept the background size at 28px and made the buttons smaller, but you may be able to just increase the size to 40px and keep the button sizes the same.  Depending on what else you have within your view, you may need to tweak things slightly, but this should get you on the right track.  I'm hoping when they release the next version of Telerik this becomes a lot easier.

EDIT:  Only tested on Firefox and Safari.  May need to add compatibility for IE / Chrome.

EDIT2:  I added line-height to fix the issue in IE and Chrome not showing the page number.

```
    input[type="text"], input[type="number"] .uneditable-input
{
    color: #555555;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 23px;
    line-height: 23px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding: 4px 6px;
    vertical-align: middle;

    line-height: 10px;
}
```

Edit3:  Using the CSS above may affect other selectLists you have in the view.  A way to get past this is to create a new class and add it to your select list.  This is how I did it.

View:

```
<form>
<select name="ReportIndex" class="select">
    <option value="1">Guest Report</option>
    <option value="2">--TBA--</option>
    <option value="3">--TBA--</option>
</select>
    <input type="submit" value="Change Report" />
</form>
```

CSS:

```
.select
{
    height: 30px !important;
    font-size: 10pt !important;
}
```

Comment: Awesome!  This definitely helped a lot.  However, the only issue I'm having now (and this is in Chrome) is that the current page textbox looks kind of messed up.  In your screen shot, the number shows up correctly, but in Chrome, it's like the text is being pushed down (like there's some kind of padding at the top).  I'll work on it though (css isn't my strongest area).  Thanks for the suggestion though, this is much better.  I really appreciate it!

Edit: Another quick question.  Do you know of a way to make the actual report toolbar taller instead of making the other elements smaller?

Comment: I believe I ran into a similar issue with Chrome.  I added a lineheight of 10 to     input[type="text"], input[type="number"] .uneditable-input and it resolved the issue.  You can make the toolbar bigger, but you will need to either use a different background or enlarge the current one (it's currently only 28px high).  I considered doing this, but the smaller icons worked better for my site.  It shouldn't be hard to adjust the buttons back to size by modifying the CSS 11px height I think.

Comment: Under ".ReportToolbar INPUT" I changed the height to 18px instead of 11, and that fixed the current page textbox to where I can see the number now.  I can live with the rest of the inconsistencies in the toolbar for now.  Now the only issue I have with the css is that I have another drop down list on the page that I use to select the report that gets run.  When I run the report, the css from the report viewer makes that drop down list get smaller.  Other than that, everything else looks good. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Added Edit3 to the answer.  It's funny because I just added the selectList to my project this morning as well.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to respond, getting pulled in a million different directions.  Your 3rd edit fixed the dropdown list changing when running the report.  There's still a small gap between the report toolbar and the report itself, but I can live with that.  I really appreciate your help Gary, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to use a Partial View here:

```
return PartialView("ReportViewer");
```

You could try returning a View and then as a second paremeter pass in a different Layout csthml page that doesnt define any css file or just the css file you need.

so something like:

```
return View("ReportViewer" "~/Views/Shared/_TestLayout.cshtml");
```

Comment: I'm going off the information that Telerik provided (it was for MVC 4, but should still work with MVC 3).  One issue is that their report viewer doesn't have Razor support yet, so I have to use an aspx page.  I think one issue may be that I'm using an aspx page and not an ascx page for the partial view, but I'm not 100% sure as I've only ever used the Razor view engine for my MVC apps.  From searching here, and other sites, I've seen that explicitly returning a partial view is "supposed" to return just the view with no additional css from the master page, but that isn't the case here.

Comment: Adding a new master page for that file did not help.  It still renders the same way.  Not sure why this is being so difficult.